# How to convert en-media to img when convert enml to html

Tags: html, ios, evernote

I'm working with evernote api on iOS, and want to translate enml to html. How to translate en-media to img? for example:

en-media:

```
<en-media type="image/jpeg" width="1200" hash="317ba2d234cd395150f2789cd574c722" height="1600" />
```

img:

```
<img src="imagePath"/>
```

I use core data to save information on iOS. So I can't give the local path of img file to "src = ". How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is embedding image data using [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

1. Find a Evernote [Resource](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Resources.php) associated with this hash code.
2. Build the following Data URI (sorry for Java syntax, I'm not very familiar with Objective C):

   String imgUrl = "data:" + resource.getMime() + ";base64," + java.util.prefs.Base64.byteArrayToBase64(resource.getData().getBody());
3. Create HTML img tag using *imgUrl* from (2).

Answer (score 0):

Note: the following solution will allow you to display the image outside of the note's content.

On [this page](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Resources.php), you'll find the following url template:

*https://host.evernote.com/shard/shardId/res/GUID*

First compile the url from some variables, then point the html image src = the url.

In ruby, you might compile the url with a method similar to this one:

```
def resource_url
    "https://#{EVERNOTE_HOST}/shard/#{self.note.notebook.user.evernote_shard_id}/res/#{self.evernote_id}"
end
```

...where `self` references the resource, `EVERNOTE_HOST` is equivalent to the host url (i.e. sandbox.evernote.com), `evernote_shard_id` is the user's shardId, and `evernote_id` is the user's guid.